# Is eval() evil in this case?

Tags: javascript, security, eval

Hi :) I'm wondering if `eval` is secure in this case :

```
!function(){
    var a = 1;
    !function(){
        var b = 2;
        try { eval.call({}, 'a'); } 
        catch (e) { console.log(e.message); }
        try { eval.call({}, 'b'); } 
        catch (e) { console.log(e.message); }
    }();
}();
```

Both calls fail. Does this mean that `eval` has no access to the surrounding scopes? In other words, using `eval.call({}, '...')` instead of `eval('...')`, can `eval` only access the object's members?

---

Some tests here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/20975485/1636522.

Comment: `eval` is only "secure" if you already know what the string will do when interpreted as JavaScript code (like in your example, where the string is a constant).  And if you do know, then there are straightforward solutions (`function() {...}`, context objects) that typically run a dozen times faster and don't have *any* of the risks that `eval` is famous for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `eval` is not with a "calling context" — a local value of `this` basically — then the execution context is the global context. [Section 10.4.2 of the spec.](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.4.2)

So this should work:

```
!function(){
    var a = 1;
    function evalWrapper() {
        var b = 2;
        try { eval('a'); console.log("yaay!"); } 
        catch (e) { console.log(e.message); }
    };
    evalWrapper.call({});
}();
```

The first scenario described in the spec is:

> If there is no calling context or if the eval code is not being evaluated by a direct call (15.1.2.1.1) to the eval function then,
>  a. Initialise the execution context as if it was a global execution context using the eval code as C as described in 10.4.1.1.

Thus, anything you do other than directly call `eval( something )` — including, if you read that referenced section, referencing the "eval" function by something other than the name "eval"! — then the code in the string is evaluated in the global context, including the global lexical context. It's therefore as if the code were not inside the surrounding function at all.

Comment: Do you think enclosing the entire code into a function makes this pattern secure?

Comment: Well if it's in a function *and* the function is called with some context so that `this` is defined.  So, like, if the function is accessed via an object property, or if you call the *surrounding* function with `.call()`.

Comment: @wared the spec is pretty weird on this point; there's probably a reason for it but I don't know what it is. I have vague memory of an old Kangax blog post on the subject, or on a related subject.

Answer (score 1):

### Additional test

Tries to access variables from the inside of the IIFE.

```
var a = 1;
!function(){
    var b = 2;
    try { eval.call(null, 'console.log(a)'); } 
    catch (e) { console.log(e.message); }
    try { eval.call(null, 'console.log(b)'); } 
    catch (e) { console.log(e.message); }
    try { eval.call({ c: 3 }, 'console.log(c)'); } 
    catch (e) { console.log(e.message); }
}();
```

Chrome :

```
1
b is not defined
c is not defined
```

### Cross browser test

Tries to access variables from the outside of the IIFE. Considering Pointy's answer, all variables except `a` should be accessible.

```
!function () {
    var a = 1;
    eval.call(window, [
        'b = 2;',
        'c = function () { return 3; };',
        'd = function d() { return 4; };',
        'function e() { return 5; };',
        'x = function () { return a; };'
    ].join(' '));
}();
var l = function (a) { console.log(a); };
try { l('window.a -> ' + window.a); } catch(e) { l(e.message); };
try { l('window.b -> ' + window.b); } catch(e) { l(e.message); };
try { l('window.c() -> ' + window.c()); } catch(e) { l(e.message); };
try { l('window.d() -> ' + window.d()); } catch(e) { l(e.message); };
try { l('window.e() -> ' + window.e()); } catch(e) { l(e.message); };
try { l('window.x() -> ' + window.x()); } catch(e) { l(e.message); };
```

Chrome 31, FF 26, IE 8-10 :

```
window.a -> undefined
window.b -> 2
window.c() -> 3
window.d() -> 4
window.e() -> 5
a is not defined
```

IE 7 does not behave as expected :

```
window.a -> undefined
window.b -> 2
window.c() -> 3
object doesn't support this property or method
function expected
window.x() -> 1
```

### IE 7 and named functions

```
eval.call(window, 'function f(){return 1}') 
!function () {
    eval.call(window, 'function g(){return 2}');
    console.log(g());
}();
console.log(f());
console.log(g());
```

It seems that named functions are part of the scope from which `eval` was called :

```
2
1
g is null or undefined
```

### Cross browser eval at window level

Actually, "cross browser" means "Chrome 31, FF 26, IE 7-10" :)

```
function evil(code, success, failure) {
    var head, script;
    script = document.createElement('script');
    script.text = [
        'try{_logevil[0](eval(\'', 
            code.replace(/('|\\)/g, '\\\$1'), 
        '\'))}catch(e){_logevil[1](e);}'
    ].join('');
    window._logevil = [success, failure];
    head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    head.appendChild(script);
    head.removeChild(script);
}
```

Usage examples :

```
evil(
    'var a = 1; alert(a); a;', 
    function (r) { console.log(r); }, 
    function (e) { console.log(e.message); }
);

// prints "1"

evil(
    'alert(b);',
    function (r) { console.log(r); }, 
    function (e) { console.log(e.message); }
);

// prints "b is not defined"
```